# FFMPEG : Obtain the system time corresponding to each frame present in a video

Tags: video, ffmpeg, duplicates, timestamp, video-capture

I am currently recording the screen using the below command on Windows 10 system,

```
ffmpeg.exe -loglevel quiet -f gdigrab -framerate 30 -i desktop -vf mpdecimate,setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -preset slow -crf 0 -threads 0 nodups.mkv
```

If I record a video for 5 mins, where 4 minutes out of it is idle. The final video obtained is only 1 minute. I want to know the system time corresponding to a specific frame from this 1 minute video. 
I tried making use of the command to obtain the frame information from this 1 minute video for 40th frame like : `ffmpeg -i nodups.mkv -vf select='eq(n,40)',showinfo -f null -`
This outputs me

```
[Parsed_showinfo_1 @ 000002455fce5dc0] n:   0 pts:   1333 pts_time:1.333   pos:   158601 fmt:yuv420p sar:0/1 s:1600x900 i:P iskey:0 type:P checksum:885ECCE2 plane_checksum:[7D89AD8E DC745BDC 0E23C369] mean:[158 128 128] stdev:[101.7 4.5 4.0
```

Is there a way to obtain the system time when this frame was captured using FFMPEG ? Any inputs will help.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because , as explained by the ffmpeg tag: Only questions about programmatic use of the FFmpeg libraries, API, or tools are on topic. Questions about interactive use of the command line tool should be asked on https://superuser.com/ or https://video.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use

`ffmpeg.exe -f gdigrab -framerate 30 -i desktop -filter_complex settb=1/1000,setpts=RTCTIME/1000-1500000000000,mpdecimate,split[out][ts];[out]setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB[out] -map [out] -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -preset fast -crf 0 -threads 0 nodups.mkv -map [ts] -f mkvtimestamp_v2 nodups.txt -vsync 0`

FFmpeg supports a data format called mkvtimestamp_v2 which stores timestamps as text in millisecond precision. So, in the command above, the input timestamps are first converted to millisecond precision with settb, then setpts is used to assign the wallclock time to each frame. But because the text format has a limited precision, we need to reduce the timestamp. That's done by subtracting 15e11. The after the mpdecimate, we split the result, sending one copy for encoding and one for metadata output.

nodups.txt will look like this

```
# timecode format v2
42721944800
42721944867
42721944933
42721945200
...
```

For frame no. X, select the Xth entry, add 15e11 (1500000000000) and then convert to a human timestamp from e.g. https://www.epochconverter.com/

Comment: Instead of RTCTime is there a way by which it can be the system time i.e the local time seen on the system ?

Comment: Not implemented. But you just need to add a fixed offset to get that.

Comment: this can be used to get sync multiple live input? I have to get sync videos with xstack filter.

Comment: This seems to give inaccurate timestamps, in my case the absolute (!) timestamps are always divisible by 1/framerate. I'm not sure why, but you can check [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76017252/3881672) and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76035873/3881672) for details and a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Gyan's answer works under linux as well. I just needed double-quotes around the long argument after filter-complex.